# How can I get the Image.data of sensor_msgs/Image in Python

Tags: sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,
I am learning turtlebot_simulator with gazebo.
I am trying to write a listener in python to subscriber the topic of 'camera/rgb/image_raw'. But I have problems in getting the Image.data for it is uint8[], I want to know how can I translate it into a normal matrix or image which can be dealt with.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144311/how-can-i-get-the-image.data-of-sensor_msgs/image-in-python/) by [Consider1001](https://answers.ros.org/users/12511/consider1001/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Converting Between ROS Images And OpenCV Images Python](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython)

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Consider1001](https://answers.ros.org/users/12511/consider1001/) on 2014-03-25**:
Thank you very much! Problem solved!